Missing value where TRUE/FALSE is needed : Canonical Correlation Analysis (cc CCA package)
I'm trying to proceed a Canonical Correlation Analysis on two different spatiotemporal datasets.
They are structured as follow : 2 large matrix with the same dimension [1:2310672, 1:288], where the first one refers to the spatial dimension (linearization of x:y matrix) and the second refers to time (288 observations). The two matrix contains missing values.
Here is the code I'm using :
cca <- cc(A_2d_chloa, A_2d_turb)

And the error I'm having :
Error in if (max(abs(Bmat - t(Bmat)))/max(abs(Bmat)) > 1e-10) stop("BMAT not symmetric.") : Missing value where TRUE/FALSE is needed

Does this error comes from the fact that I have NA values in my datasets eventhough the function description says this function accept missing values ?
Thank's in advance for your help.

The first code chunk shows an NA value does not cause an error.
cc() uses the geigen() function and this is where the error comes from. Try replacing X with your first matrix in the last two lines of code and see if that reproduces the error. That may help you diagnose the problem.
library(CCA)

# Sample data works when inserting NA
data(nutrimouse)
X <- as.matrix(nutrimouse$gene[, 1:10])
Y <- as.matrix(nutrimouse$lipid)
X[1, "ACAT1"] <- NA
result <- cc(X, Y)

# Replace X with your first matrix and see if this recreates the error
Cxx <- var(X, na.rm = TRUE, use = "pairwise") + diag(0, ncol(X))
if (max(abs(Cxx - t(Cxx)))/max(abs(Cxx)) > 1e-10) stop("BMAT not symmetric.") else("okay")
#> [1] "okay"

Created on 2024-04-27 with reprex v2.1.0

This has reproduced my error, Cxx is then an matrix with several values and some NA values. Should I remove the column in my dataset where Cxx contain NA value ?

This represents 2690 and 3760 for the two datasets on a 55696 size matrix.

Maybe see where abs(Cxx - t(Cxx)) / abs(Cxx) > 1e-10 is TRUE
